# Backup from subversion 1.7 and restore it to subversion 1.6

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I have list of subversion repository in standalone linux machine where the subversion version is 1.7. I want to take backup of repositories using svndump and restore it to my central subversion server which is running on subversion-1.6.

is it possible take svndump from subversion-1.7 and load it subversion-1.6?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Dumps are identical in (at least) these versions, only internal repository format was modified